# Looping over with open() thows IOError

Tags: file, python-3.x, io

I am iterating over several DB records and writing data from their respective BLOB fields into files:

```
def build(self, records):
    """
    Builds openimmo.anhang
    """
    result = None
    anh_records = [r for r in records if type(r) == anhaenge]
    if not anh_records:
        return result
    anhang = []
    print('RECORDS: ' + str(len(anh_records)))
    for anh_record in anh_records:
        if anh_record.daten:
            __, path = mkstemp()
            with open(path, 'wb') as target:
                target.write(anh_record.daten)
            anh = openimmo.anhang()
            anh.anhangtitel = anh_record.anhangtitel
            anh.format = 'image/jpeg' #MIMEUtil.getmime(path)
            anh.daten = openimmo.daten()
            anh.daten.pfad = path
            anh.location = id2location.get(anh_record.location)
            anh.gruppe = id2gruppe.get(anh_record.gruppe)
            anhang.append(anh)
    try:
        result.validateBinding()
    except:
        self.log.err('Could not build "anhang": ' + str(result))
    if anhang:
        result = openimmo.anhaenge()
        result.anhang = anhang
    return result
```

This, however produces the following error:

```
RECORDS: 5
Message: "[Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/tmpo54qfq'
daemon panic:
Caught unexpected exception in _main() on 2014-08-20 11:53:37.918353
Message: "[Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/tmpo54qfq'" of type "<class 'IOError'>"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_core-1.0-py3.2.egg/homie/serv/daemon.py", line 345, in __run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_core-1.0-py3.2.egg/homie/serv/service.py", line 72, in _main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_core-1.0-py3.2.egg/homie/api/itf.py", line 127, in export
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_openimmodb-0.2_indev-py3.2.egg/openimmodb/itf.py", line 51, in _retrieve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_openimmodb-0.2_indev-py3.2.egg/openimmodb/conv.py", line 27, in decode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_openimmodb-0.2_indev-py3.2.egg/openimmodb/factories/openimmo/immobilie.py", line 60, in build
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie_openimmodb-0.2_indev-py3.2.egg/openimmodb/factories/openimmo/anhaenge.py", line 30, in build
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/tmpo54qfq'
```

According to `lsof` the whole process has over 5k open files:

```
# lsof| grep python3| wc -l
5375
```

I checked it several times: I am using `with open(file) as desc` everywhere in the code, when I open a file.
Shouldn't the files be closed automatically at the end of each `with` block, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempfile.mkstemp()` opens a file for you:

```
fd, path = mkstemp()
with open(fd, 'wb') as target:
    # os.close(fd) is called automatically
```

You don't need `open(path)` that opens *another* file (with the same name).

You could use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` instead of `tempfile.mkstemp()`.

Comment: OMG, how couldn't I see this.
I just investigated the tempfile module after your answer for better understanding and found `mktemp()` (without the 's').
I think I will use this one - just to be sure.
Thank you.

Comment: @RichardNeumann: don't use `mktemp()` (as its docs say). Both `mkstemp()` and `NamedTemporaryFile()` should be fine. The latter returns `target` directly (`target.name` is its path).

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian:
Thnaks again. I will look into it.
PS: My _exact_ mistake is even documented here: http://www.logilab.org/17873  :-P

Comment: as the code in my answer shows you can pass fd to open() directly, to get a file object i.e., the logilab's fix opens the second file unnecessarily.

Comment: I am using NamedTemporaryFile() now, as you suggested.